# Software for creating HTML5 Interactive animation & 3D animation

Tags: html, 3d, animation, interactive-fiction

I'm working on an interactive animation project in HTML5. Currently I'm using Adobe animate cc, but animate cc does not support 3D animation in HTML5 document. I'm looking to switch to some other software which support high quality animation (2D & 3D both) and interactivity. Which are the softwares that support interactive animation (2D & 3D)? It could be both paid, open source and other then HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Some more information would be really beneficial. What do you animate? Just Keyframe animation? Do you need a physics engine for some FX? What about particles and VFX? Skeleton animation?

There are plenty of options:

May look different than what you used to, but it's worth a try:

- **Spline** (https://spline.design/)
- **Womp** (https://www.womp.com/)

Both are online tools, integrate interactive functionallity and can be fun to use.

Other than that (and for a much more classical approach), I would suggest one of the following solutions (any of which can be used by art and animation tools of your choice, e.g Blender, Cinema4D, Modo or Maya):

- **Godot Engine** - (https://godotengine.org/) fully fledged Game Engine with good HTML5 support
- **Rogue Engine** - (https://rogueengine.io/) Engine based on ThreeJS, perfectly compatible with modern Webbrowsers and HTML5, provides an Editor for ThreeJS based projects.
- Babylon.js - (https://www.babylonjs.com/) very strong and professional 3D engine for HTML5, including stuff like physics and material editor. All in all good tools and strong engine
- **ThreeJS** - (https://threejs.org/) basic 3D framework for Javascript/HTML5, popular choice, but lacks of features like physics engine or even a material editor (by default).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) for 3D modelling, animation and texturing, and one of its multiple addons for exporting to the web.

- [Blend4Web](https://www.blend4web.com)
- [Verge 3D](https://www.soft8soft.com/verge3d/)
- [X3DOM](https://www.x3dom.org/documentation/tutorials/blender-export/)

Blender can do 2D animation with [Grease Pencil](https://www.blender.org/features/grease-pencil/) feature, though I don't think it can be exported, and can othwerwise simulate 2D animation with 3D elements exportable to the web

Answer (score -1):

I invite you to try [Polygonjs](https://polygonjs.com) (disclaimer: I'm running it), which is a procedural webgl editor based on threejs.

The editor is fully node-based, and allows the creation of 3D scenes in a non-destructive manner.

Some nodes are specialized in geometry manipulation or shader creation (similarly to the vfx software Houdini) and some in adding animations and behaviours to the scene objects (similarly to Unreal).

It also allows exporting to vanilla js, react, vue, webflow, which makes it easy to integrate into most websites, so it seems like it could suit your requirements.

It's also free to try, no time limit. And the core library is [open source](https://github.com/polygonjs/polygonjs), to make it easy to create custom nodes if needed.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a summary or description of your software